# Как сделать анимацию LinearLayout с изменением позиций нажатия его внутренних элементов

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

У меня есть `LinearLayout` в котором есть три `TableLayout`, в каждом по три `TableRow`, в которых есть много кнопок. Когда я делаю анимацию уменьшения `LinearLayout` , то на экране все уменьшается как надо, но позиция нажатий на кнопки остается прежним. То есть после анимации, когда я нажимаю на кнопки ничего не происходит, но если я буду нажимать на позиции кнопок которые были до анимации (BEFORE ANIMATION) , то тогда кнопки нажимаются и активируются. Как это исправить?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй по окончании анимации задать новое положение Layout

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.setScaleX(scaleX);
layout.setScaleY(scaleY);
```